# AngularJS: set same height for divs in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm an AngularJS newbie developing an app in phonegap using Angular + Angular Mobile UI.

I have a list of divs in my template file inside Bootstrap columns **WITHOUT USING jQuery**. I need to square divs applying an height responsive to their width in Bootstrap columns. It should be a really simple script but I can't handle.

Here is my template:

**template.html**

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerIndex as Ctrl" item-list>    
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" >
        <div class="col-xs-4 object-list-container">
            <div class="object-list" >
                <p ng-bind-html="item.name"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Here's my **controller**:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ControllerIndex', function ($scope, $http, $element) {
    $scope.items =[];

    $http.get(baseUrl +'data/item.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.items = data.item;
    }).error(function(){
        commonError();
    });
```

});

and here my **directive**:

```
angular.module('app').directive('itemList', function($timeout){
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        //I tried a lot of things
        $timeout(function(){
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("object-list");
                console.log(elements); //Gives an array of 2
                var elementsLenght = elements.length;
                console.log(elementsLenght); //Gives 0!!!!!!
            });

             //Get the max height and set to the other div, but i can't enter this cycle
             for (var i = 0; i < elementsLenght; i++) {
                    var elementHeight = elements[i].offsetHeight;
                    //console.log(elementHeight);
                    if (elements[i].offsetHeight > maxHeight) {
                        maxHeight = elementHeight;
                    }
                }    


        //Attempt number 2
var angularElement = angular.element($element);
 var elementObject = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('.object-list'));
console.log(elementObject); //Gives a T object with lenght 0
            var xx =  angular.element(elementObject[0]);
            console.log(xx.offsetHeight);
            console.log('elementObject: ', angular.element(elementObject[0])); //Gives html       


       }
    }
});
```

I think i'm missing something. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your directive to be part of ng-repeat and detect when the ng-repeat finishes loading, and in that directive, once you detect that the last one has finished loading, do your first attempted solution.

template:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerIndex as Ctrl">    
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" item-list>
        <div class="col-xs-4 object-list-container">
            <div class="object-list" >
                <p ng-bind-html="item.name"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('itemList', function($timeout){
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
             if ($scope.$last){
                 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("object-list");
                 var maxHeight = 0;
                 //Get the max height and set to the other div
                 $timeout(function(){
                    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                       var elementHeight = elements[i].offsetHeight;
                       //console.log(elementHeight);
                       if (elements[i].offsetHeight > maxHeight) {
                           maxHeight = elementHeight;
                       }
                    }    
                 });
             }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Arathi Sreekumar. Now i get the correct elements.lenght, but when i access elements[i].offsetHeight i get 0 because if i console.log(elements[i]) it prints html and not an element. Can you explain me why? thank you!

Comment: elements[i] is an html element. So that is correct. try printing elements[i].offsetHeight. If its printing 0, that might be because its still not rendered on the dom, unfortunately. I cannot say without actually looking at the code and trying out different things.

Comment: Yes, it's printing 0. What you need to see more?

Comment: I would need a sample plunker/jsfiddle to say anything more. You could try adding the timeout around the for loop.

Comment: Yeah man, it did the trick! Can you edit your answer so i can approve it?  thank you!

Comment: This could be because when a link function is running, the dom might not be updated yet. Done updating my answer.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar there is a typo if if condition should be $scope.$last

Comment: @Aivar Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I battled with the same issue for a long time. Binding the heights of divs together when the height of any is modified. This is an angular directive that helps me till today.

```
var app = angular.module('app'); //insert your module name instead

function bind_height() {
    function doforthiselem(me) {
        var value = $(me).attr("bind-height");
        var elems = $("[bind-height='" + value + "']");
        var heights = elems.toArray().map(function (elem) { return $(elem).height(); });
        if (Math.max.apply(me, heights) > Math.min.apply(me, heights)) $(me).height(Math.max.apply(me, heights));
    }
    $("[bind-height]").each(function () {
        doforthiselem(this);
    });
}

$(window).load(function () {
    if (typeof app == "undefined") bind_height();
});

app.directive("bindHeight", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            bind_height();
            element.bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
                bind_height();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

To use, you need to set the [bind-height] attribute values of the elements whose heights you wish to bind to the same value. For example,

```
<div>
    <div bind-height="my-binding" style="height: 80px;">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <div bind-height="my-binding" style="height: 25px;">
        <p>Hello America</p>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <div bind-height="my-binding" style="height: 63px;">
        <p>Shoot for the stars</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

All divs whose [bind-height] attributes have "my-binding" as their values will have their heights bound to the height of the "tallest" div. If one of them is modified, and has its height changed, the others will be updated too.

In an ng-repeat situation, this also works well...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" bind-height="item-height-bind">
    <!--do stuff-->
</div>
```

If your elements are in columns of three per row, you might which to bind them in threes ...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" bind-height="item-height-{{ceil(($index + 1)/3)}}">
    <!--do stuff-->
</div>
```

I hope this helps you as it did me.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a jQuery based answer. I don't want to use jQuery, thanks anyway!

Comment: Really? Why is that?

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but the $ is about jquery namespace. I think that the load method is not supported $(window).load() without jquery. Can you explain me how i should use it?

Comment: The windows load function is only there in case you do not wish to use angular ... You might as well remove it. And yea, jQuery is required. I just wonder why you are required to not use it. Why fight zombies with a pocket knife when you have a Katana?

Comment: 1)Trying to use Angular in the right way. 2)Avoid jquery because of app performaces

Answer (score 0):

To improve  [arathi-sreekumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3688348/arathi-sreekumar) answer I modified it to get the full working code

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerIndex as Ctrl">    
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" item-list="object-list">
        <div class="col-xs-4 object-list-container">
            <div class="object-list" >
                <p ng-bind-html="item.name"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Now a directive gets a CSS class as a parameter and sets elements' heights to the max height

```
let myDirective = 'itemList';
angular.module('app').directive('itemList', function($timeout){
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
             if ($scope.$last){
                 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName($attrs[myDirective]);
                 var maxHeight = 0;
                 //Get the max height
                 $timeout(function(){
                    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                       var elementHeight = elements[i].offsetHeight;
                       //console.log(elementHeight);
                       if (elements[i].offsetHeight > maxHeight) {
                           maxHeight = elementHeight;
                       }
                    }
                    // set to max height to divs

                    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
                        if (elements[j].offsetHeight < maxHeight) {
                            angular.element(elements[j]).height(maxHeight);
                            console.log(elements[j].offsetHeight);
                        }
                    }


                 });
             }
        }
    }
});
```